# AngularJS 1: How to bind index as expression to an array in html?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having little issue. I am trying to display some data using ng-repeat like that:

```
ng-repeat="color in apples[{{index}}].color"
```

where

```
$scope.index = $stateParams.index;
```

However, I get a a syntax error.

What is a proper way to dynamically add index to array in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use loop index:

```
ng-repeat="color in apples[$index].color"
```

or

```
ng-repeat="color in apples[index].color"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me: when I try to display values below the ng-repeat for color, I have an empty object. ( I display values as {{color}})

Comment: And in HTML code I have: <!-- ngRepeat: color in apples[index].color -->

Comment: What is the error message? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Alright, this worked :) I had to rename index to pp.index, as I use controller as syntax :)

Comment: You can use ng-repeat only on the iterable items. Check if apples[index] has any property attribute. Also share complete code. It is hard to understand whether apples is an array or object